# Connected App to access the Partner Learning Camp

Tags: connected-apps

When ever we try and access the `Partner Learning Camp`, it always tries to authenticate the user against the most recent org (demo, developer, or client) the user logged into.

This is a pain.

I would like to create a `Connected App` in our org, to make the process seamless.

After a lot of fiddling around I am starting to believe its not possible.

When you try to login into the `Partner Learning Camp` it sends the browser to:

```
https://partnerlearningcamp.salesforce.com/services/auth/sso/Partner_Success_SSO?startURL=%2Fs%2Fbrowse-catalog
```

Which `302` redirects to:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3MVG9mclR62wycM2o_bV3o61.dATFdxz4ccUQw9S8a0GwUAYnrXnhD1cLQLEQQZFJHttRlEVTDr.nOktOHTFc&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fpartnerlearningcamp.salesforce.com%2Fservices%2Fauthcallback%2FPartner_Success_SSO&scope=id&state=CAAAAYKjrPnwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwAAAA7o_JeIFIm9MYpkMT7w2iq7btyExyTwrFywx-zVwVfkb-iN6jmanTl4rXU5DsPqgVfOyvneLMPgMYcQ0cUMQpSq2CVeEvZmXIh0Nvo-4QuDHL6-E9X1EfP02Jc5wyk2cV0DT6aqjBeUPh07dy-1136vBwRbYpRCtc_8QfShHOGyYa18Xw8pgP3ER88YD0OMbQqyupu0ipzAR-W9YLYzF_3rFwpSfSYrzL8DnsQ9tQ1oZQUByXg3dCatcit37VP3-7fqu8LqPTQkZSYNjDaXZh58SjrPRUuXsjEiVxbA6ArmKC
```

Which is the core Salesforce Login endpoint.

I believe it is this endpoint that is deciding which org the user most recently authenticated with.

I've tried creating the `Connected App` and setting the `Start URL` to:

```
https://mycompany.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3MVG9mclR62wycM2o_bV3o61.dATFdxz4ccUQw9S8a0GwUAYnrXnhD1cLQLEQQZFJHttRlEVTDr.nOktOHTFc&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fpartnerlearningcamp.salesforce.com%2Fservices%2Fauthcallback%2FPartner_Success_SSO&scope=id&state=CAAAAYKjrPnwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwAAAA7o_JeIFIm9MYpkMT7w2iq7btyExyTwrFywx-zVwVfkb-iN6jmanTl4rXU5DsPqgVfOyvneLMPgMYcQ0cUMQpSq2CVeEvZmXIh0Nvo-4QuDHL6-E9X1EfP02Jc5wyk2cV0DT6aqjBeUPh07dy-1136vBwRbYpRCtc_8QfShHOGyYa18Xw8pgP3ER88YD0OMbQqyupu0ipzAR-W9YLYzF_3rFwpSfSYrzL8DnsQ9tQ1oZQUByXg3dCatcit37VP3-7fqu8LqPTQkZSYNjDaXZh58SjrPRUuXsjEiVxbA6ArmKC
```

But the `Connected App` give a generic error of:

> A general data error occurred with your entries

**Questions**

1. Is it even possible to achieve this?
2. If so, what am I doing wrong?
3. And, how to I make it work?